# wxPython: Resizing a notebook within a notebook

Tags: python, wxpython

I have made a GUI where there are 4 main tabs, the 4 tabs are then split in half, with another notebook on the left and an empty panel on the right (a graph will go here). See image for below of my GUI.[image]

The problem I am having is that I cannot resize the notebook on the left to fit the contents of the notebook. By fitting its contents I mean I want the right hand side of the notebook to be pulled in. I also want the size to remain fixed so If I resized the window by clicking and dragging the right hand corner it wont resize the notebook, but the panel on the right will get bigger/smaller depending on whether the user clicked and dragged.

Code below:

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class MyFrame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.notebook_2 = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_2_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.notebook_2_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.notebook_2_pane_3 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.notebook_2_pane_4 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.notebook_3 = wx.Notebook(self.notebook_2_pane_1, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_3a = wx.Notebook(self.notebook_3, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_4 = wx.Notebook(self.notebook_3, -1, style=0)
        self.panel_2a = wx.Panel(self.notebook_4, -1)
        self.panel_2b = wx.Panel(self.notebook_3a, -1)
        self.panel_2c = wx.Panel(self.notebook_3a, -1)
        self.panel_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_3, -1)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2_pane_1, -1)
        self.grid_1 = wx.grid.Grid(self.panel_2a, -1, size=(1, 1))
        self.grid_2 = wx.grid.Grid(self.notebook_4, -1, size=(1, 1))
        self.bws_btn = wx.Button(self.panel_2b, -1, "Browse...")
        self.tctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_2b, -1) 
        self.filename = wx.StaticText(self.panel_2b, -1, 'File:')
        self.limitdata = wx.StaticText(self.panel_2b, -1, 'Limit Data:')
        self.tctrl3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_2b, -1, '200') 
        self.disp_sel_pk = wx.StaticText(self.panel_2c, -1, 'Display Selected Data')
        self.toggle = wx.ToggleButton(self.panel_2c, 1, 'Toggle')
        self.add_peak = wx.StaticText(self.panel_2c, -1, 'Add Data:')
        self.add_peak_tctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_2c, -1, 'Test') 
        self.add_peak_btn = wx.Button(self.panel_2c, -1, "Add")
        self.capt_click = wx.Button(self.panel_2c, -1, "Capture Mouse Click")   
        self.save_btn = wx.Button(self.panel_2a, -1, "Save as CSV file")
        self.update_btn = wx.Button(self.panel_2a, -1, "Update")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_2")
        self.SetMinSize((800, 600))

        self.grid_1.CreateGrid(30, 3)
        self.grid_1.SetRowLabelSize(0) # hide the rows
        self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(0, "Data ID")
        self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(1, "Test")
        self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(2, "Frquency")

        self.grid_2.CreateGrid(30, 13)
        self.grid_2.SetRowLabelSize(30)
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_5.Add(self.filename, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_4.Add(self.bws_btn, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_4.Add(self.tctrl, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_6.Add(self.limitdata, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_6.Add(self.tctrl3, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_5)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_4)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_6)


        sizer_1a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1a.Add(self.grid_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1a.Add(self.save_btn, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_1a.Add(self.update_btn, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        self.panel_2b.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.panel_2a.SetSizer(sizer_1a)

        sizer_1b = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_4a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_5a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_6a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_7a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_8a = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_4a.Add(self.disp_sel_pk, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_5a.Add(self.toggle, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        sizer_6a.Add(self.add_peak, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)        
        sizer_7a.Add(self.add_peak_tctrl, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)      
        sizer_7a.Add(self.add_peak_btn, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)  
        sizer_8a.Add(self.capt_click, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT | wx.Left | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, border=10)   
        sizer_1b.Add(sizer_4a)
        sizer_1b.Add(sizer_5a)
        sizer_1b.Add(sizer_6a)
        sizer_1b.Add(sizer_7a)
        sizer_1b.Add(sizer_8a)
        self.panel_2c.SetSizer(sizer_1b)

        self.notebook_3.AddPage(self.notebook_3a, "Inputs")
        self.notebook_3.AddPage(self.notebook_4, "Results")
        self.notebook_3a.AddPage(self.panel_2b, "Graph")
        self.notebook_3a.AddPage(self.panel_2c, "Calc")
        self.notebook_4.AddPage(self.panel_2a, "Info")
        self.notebook_4.AddPage(self.grid_2, "Info2")
        sizer_3.Add(self.notebook_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_3.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.notebook_2_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_3)
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_1, "Setup")
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_2, "Optimisation")
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_3, "Algorithm")
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_4, "Data")
        sizer_2.Add(self.notebook_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        sizer_2.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_2 = MyFrame1(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_2)
    frame_2.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code to see how proportions are given to widgets when added to container sizers in order to produce what you want.
You must set the panel proportion to 1 (occupy 100% of all space available for the widget) and the notebook proportion to 0 (occupy the minimal space needed to hold its child widgets):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# generated by wxGlade HG on Sat Jan 21 15:09:27 2012

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_1_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, -1)
        self.notebook_2 = wx.Notebook(self.notebook_1_pane_1, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_2_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self.notebook_2_pane_1, -1, "button_1")
        self.notebook_2_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_2, -1)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1_pane_1, -1)
        self.notebook_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, -1)
        self.notebook_1_pane_3 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, -1)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        self.panel_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 0))
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_3.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        self.notebook_2_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_3)
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_1, "tab1")
        self.notebook_2.AddPage(self.notebook_2_pane_2, "tab2")

        sizer_2.Add(self.notebook_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)      #<- notebook,proportion 0
        sizer_2.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)         #<- panel,   proportion 1

        self.notebook_1_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_1, "tab1")
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_2, "tab2")
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_3, "tab3")
        sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]